# Prove theorem about bases

Tags: general-topology

I was attempting to prove this theorem, and got lost on the second part of the proof.

Theorem:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\tau$ if and only if

$(1) \mathcal{B} \subset \tau$ and

$(2)$ for each set $U$ in $\tau$ and point $p$ in $U$ there is a set $V$ in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $p \in V \subset U$.

This was supposed to be done using the following definition:

Let $\tau$ be a topology on a set $X$, and let $\mathcal{B} \subset \tau$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology $\tau$ if and only if every open set in $\tau$ is the union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. If $B \in \mathcal{B}$, we say $B$ is a basis element. Note that $B$ is an element of the basis of $\mathcal{B}$, but a subset of the set $X$.

Attempt:

($\Rightarrow$)Obviously $(1)$ is given in the definition, so it suffices to prove $(2)$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, any open set $U$ can be expressed as a union $\bigcup\limits B_x$ of basis elements. Then $U=\bigcup\limits B_x$ . Let $p \in U$. Then $p \in B_x$ for some $x$ and $B_x \subset U$, proving $(2)$.

($\Leftarrow$)

For this direction can I just pick an arbitrary $U \in \tau$, then by condition $(2)$, for each $x \in U$, there exists a $B_x$ containing $x$, with $x \in B_x \subset U$, and then $U= \bigcup\limits B_x$? So since each open set is a union of sets satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$, this collection of sets is a basis?

Comment: That is indeed how the reverse direction is proved. You union the basic neighborhoods of every single point in $U$, and get $U$. It's clever--$U$ is the union of an indexed collection of basis elements, indexed by $U$ itself!

Comment: It''s fine. The Axiom of Choice is needed to get $\{(x,B_x):x\in U\}$ but you can avoid this: For each $x\in U\in\tau$ let $V_U(x)=\{b\in B: x\in b\subseteq U\}$ and let $W_U=\cup_{x\in U}V_U(x).$ Then $W_U\subseteq B$ and $\cup W_U=U.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can prove it that way, but we can avoid making any choices : given $U \in \tau$ we can define $$\mathcal{B}_U = \{B \in \mathcal{B}\mid B \subseteq U\}$$

Then I claim that $\bigcup \mathcal{B}_U = U$.

If $x \in U$, we apply (2) to get a $V \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$. But then $V \in \mathcal{B}_U$ by definition and so $x \in \bigcup \mathcal{B}_U$, and the reverse inclusion is obvious: all $B \in \mathcal{B}_U$ are subsets of $U$, hence so is their union.

So any $U \in \tau$ is a union of base elements and we're done.